# visual studio can't communicate with xcode

Tags: c#, xcode, cocoa, visual-studio-mac

I have installed Visual Studio for mac and Xcode 7.3.1
I try to make a Cocoa app with Visual studio.
When I try to open storybord from visual studio, I have this error:

> visual studio can't communicate with xcode

Somebody can help me?
Regards, Luca

Comment: are you sure 7.3.1 is supported? Current Xcode version is 8.3.2

Comment: I know that the current version of Xcode is 8.3.2, but on my mac 10.11 I can install until the 7.3.1.

Comment: You need to upgrade to 10.12 to install new dev tools. at the moment, it is still possible to submit to the app store with Xcode 7 but that is likely to change.